# Keep base url constant with Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I'm looking for a library/extension for JQuery or plain old Javascript that will load partials via ajax but change all relative paths to be relative to the address it's loaded to, not loaded from.

I've explored using an iFrame, but I'm making an extension for Google Chrome and that option is not possible because of several constraints. Using a `base` tag isn't an option because it would change for the entire page.

Comment: can you provide some examples of what you are looking for?  Such as an example of the URL the page may have and the URL that may get used in the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a way to get the URL of the page so that you can keep the base URL and dynamically change the path?

The following will get that information

if the URL was something like this

```
http://www.mywidget.com/Lets/Play/Games


 This one here will get the full URL of http://www.mywidget.com/Lets/Play/Games
 var urlHref = window.location.href;


  This one here will get the Host Name of www.mywidget.com
  var urlHostName = window.location.hostname;

  This one here will return the pathname of /Lets/Play/Games
  var urlPathName = window.location.pathname;
```